# Real time audio streaming and broadcasting using C# over the net for mobile clients

Tags: c#, mobile, streaming, shoutcast

I'm trying to work out a way to to record and broadcast audio in real time with a mobile to a group of receiving mobile clients.

I was looking at shoutcast/icecast to relay the audio but these seem to be old technology.  I've been reading about SIP, Jabber, Red, Jingle, etc., but find it a bit confusing.

I'm beginning to think I could use HTML5 browser client (i.e. websockets) to capture and send the audio somehow.  Is there a slicker way of doing this using C# as typed code is more comfortable to work with?

Comment: "I was looking at shoutcast/icecast to relay the audio but these seem to be old technology."  What makes you say that, and what difference does it make?  They are simply HTTP servers for sending a live stream, and they work great.  You're going to need to be more specific with your question to get a decent answer anyway.  How many clients?  Does it need to be compatible with browser players, or is a native app good enough?  What is your latency requirement?  How about audio quality?  What kind of content are you streaming?